WITHOUT deleting any of the enclosed folders(!) I wish to delete/move vscode workspace to a subfolder
I accidentally created a vscode workspace at my Documents directory. I would like either change root folder for this workspace to a subfolder or remove the workspace, without deleting all the files and folders in Documents!
I tried deleting the workspace in the vscode Navigator but it doesn't offer that option on right-click. I looks up remove workspace on google and got garbage tutorials and answers that don't answer my question. I have looked at the vscode documentation and found no reference to removing or moving a workspace
